# MOSFET drain the same with load or no load and at any voltage level (12-34 V)

Tags: mosfet

I have a simple circuit to switch a 1 MHz signal across a resistive load with an adjustable load supply voltage range of 12-34 V (the circuit board has a 12V regulator for circuit board components).

The signal at the drain looks the same, is the same, regardless of supply voltage, and with or without the load connected. I've replaced the IRF510 twice as a shotgun fix; no difference.

[image: Circuit Board]

Yellow = Gate, Blue = Drain
[image: IRF51- Yellow=Gate, Blue=Drain]

Comment: Negative diode drop voltage on the drain is suspicious. Are you sure the supply voltage polarity is correct?

Comment: What is the load value ? Also, do you have any kind of galvanic isolation on your board ? I see that you have GND, minus sign and earth symbol ...

Comment: Supply voltage polarity is correct.  

Load value is about 1Mohm. But it looks the same with or without load.

Comment: Common ground throughout.